# the call to an firebase functions function never succeed

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling to a function i have in firebase functions and when i try to get the data returned the function never succeed.
I looked for the solution but i didn't find it,

```
tornaposicio(12.9, 13.8).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String[]> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Exception e = task.getException();
            if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                Object details = ffe.getDetails();
            }
            i("Task didn't succeed", ".");


        } else {
            i("PARECE QUE FUNCIONA:",".");
            String[] info =  task.getResult();
            i("Task succesfull", info[0]);

        }

    }
});
```

---

```
private Task<String[]> tornaposicio(double latitud, double longitud) {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    HashMap<String, Double> posicio = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    posicio.put("latitud", latitud);
    posicio.put("longitud", longitud);

    return mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("tornaposicio")
            .call(posicio)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String[]>() {
                @Override
                public String[] then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult>task) throws Exception {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.


                    result = (String[]) task.getResult().getData();


                    return result;

                }
            });
```

The code always enter in "!task.isSuccessful" and i want the opposite.

Comment: If the Cloud Function failed, the exception you get contains information about that failure. Log `e.toString()` to learn more.

Comment: i did it and says "com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: INTERNAL", i looked for and it seems very bad. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please add the entire error message and stack trace to your question. It might also help if you show the minimal Cloud Functions code that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is almost certainly an error in your Cloud Functions code. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Fortunately, the problem was solved yesterday by my project mate, ty